# Routing POST requests from CloudFront to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I have a website distributed with CloudFront, with S3 as an origin. I've written a Lambda function that takes a contact form submission and sends the email along with SES. The Lambda test out just fine : )

But, I'm clueless when it comes to routing POST requests from CloudFront to that backend Lambda function. How do I do this?

**Update:** Okay, I've got the API Gateway test triggering the Lambda function just fine, but I can't seem to call it from CloudFront (or rather using a curl command to my domain set up with CloudFront).

Do I need to list my domain as a custom domain in API Gateway?

If I list the path `/api/*` in my CloudFront Behaviors, do I have to mirror that in my API Gateway set up? So, does my API Gateway need to start with `/api` before I add specific resources?

**Update 2** I think I needed to leave or remove the /dev off the end of the API Gateway URL. dev being my stage.

**Update 3** Okay, it feels one step away now. I've got everything hooked up. The test request hits cloudfront, it forwards to api gateway, gateway calls lambda (at this point I'm shaking my head at how complicated we've made all this), and lambda sends back success or failure to api gateway, and we're peachy. Except, I get MethodNotAllowed when I do it from curl or the browser. Do I need to add an IAM role to CloudFront to access API Gateway?

**Update 4** Still not working. And now, I'm back to getting my usual 404 error page that my Default Origin (S3). Seems like serverless is a fading dream.

**Update 5** Trying a different approach, recommended here: https://serverfault.com/a/839368 The idea is to use API Gateway's Custom Domain name features with a subdomain like api.example.com and then use a Route53 Alias record to direct subdomain traffic to API Gateway. This could work. Then CloudFront would handle traffic to example.com and www.example.com, and API Gateway would get requests to api.example.com. Now the challenging bit is that in HTML forms the action attribute will have to go to a different subdomain. Let's see what kinds of errors and crazy behavior we get : (

Comment: Yes I believe your API paths in API Gateway will need to be prefixed with `/api`

Comment: @MarkB, still not working, but almost there. When I send a POST request via curl in the terminal, I still get the 404 from my S3 origin. The precedence in CloudFront seems right. Not sure what's up.

Comment: Okay, so now it's API Gateway that responds in to my curl request, but it says 'Method Not Allowed on that Resource'. Note for people who get this far, you have to leave off the leading `/` in your path pattern in CloudFront Behaviors.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/ :-(

Comment: I wish I could just skip API Gateway!!! Ugghghghgh : (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you would setup API Gateway in front of your Lambda function so it can be called via a POST request. It sounds like you may already have that part done?

Then if you want the POST to go through CloudFront you would add a second origin in CloudFront that points to your API Gateway.

Comment: My CloudFront doesn't give me the option to list API gateway as an origin. It only shows me s3 origins. I have already set up and deployed the API in gateway.

Comment: You'll need to add it as a custom origin instead of picking from the list.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working.  I'm doing something in the 80 steps needed to get to HelloWorld wrong on this.

Comment: Then welcome to the AWS world, dude. 8-) A lot of things _must_ be done in damn 80 steps there.

Comment: Hahaa, ah the future is here. Cloud computing. Yeah right.

Comment: Everything comes at cost. Even win-wins. :-)

Comment: Why would you add CloudFront in front of API Gateway? API Gateway uses CloudFront internally already. It doesn't add any value.

Normally you would use S3 + Static to host your static assets and API Gateway for your API (you'll need to enable CORS).

Comment: @JohnMcKim I see people asking about placing CloudFront in front of API Gateway quite a bit. Yes API Gateway uses CloudFront internally for some caching, but there are lots of CloudFront features that aren't exposed by API Gateway, for example Lambda@Edge.

Answer (score 2):

This is all possible, but its tricky to configure. To help I created an [open-source boilerplate app](https://github.com/nzoschke/gofaas) that correctly sets up:

- A static site with CloudFront and S3
- An API with API Gateway and Lambda
- CORS between the static site and API
- Optional OAuth 2.0 and JWT cookie for the static site

See [this static JavaScript app](https://github.com/nzoschke/gofaas/blob/master/web/static/js/app.js) for an example of a static site POSTing to an API backed by Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're using as your backend (which language, framework, etc.), there are different ways, but 'em all about one thing: [Invoke](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)

Kind-of the most generic call - HTTP is right there, the API call examples by language are referenced at the end of the doc.

Comment: If I try to use that directly from the browser, I'd need to only support AJAX. No?

Comment: Keeping in mind how broad "AJAX" is - yeah, right, that's it.  :-) But, true - you need a gateway to bind them with CF, one way or another. Seems that there's no direct connection between two, except for very recent http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html which is in preview now.